Unable to access Objective-C types in Swift when building with Bazel
I'm trying to build a mixed Swift/Objective-C library using Bazel, but Swift code cannot access types defined in the Objective-C header. I've spent nearly two weeks researching and trying various solutions found in Bazel documentation and other sources, but none have worked.
The project is BSText, with some Objective-C code.
The key files are:
BSText.h (umbrella header with Objective-C type definitions)
Swift files in BSText/ directory that need to access Objective-C types
Full source code: BSText GitHub Repository
Setup
The BSText library has an umbrella header containing Objective-C declarations BSText/Bstext.h
My Bazel build file:
# Objective-C header target
objc_library(
    name = "BSTextObjC",
    hdrs = ["BSText/BSText.h"],
    sdk_frameworks = [
        "Foundation",
        "UIKit",
        "CoreText",
    ],
    includes = ["BSText"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

# Swift library target
swift_library(
    name = "BSTextLib",
    module_name = "BSText",
    srcs = glob([
        "BSText/**/*.swift",
    ]),
    swiftc_inputs = ["BSText/BSText.h"],
    deps = [":BSTextObjC"],
    copts = [
        "-enable-bare-slash-regex",
        "-suppress-warnings",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

apple_bundle_version(
    name = "BSText_Version",
    build_version = "1",
    short_version_string = "1.1.13",
)

apple_xcframework(
    name = "BSText",
    bundle_id = "com.geekbruce.bstext",
    bundle_name = "BSText",
    infoplists = ["Framework/BSText/Info.plist"],
    minimum_os_versions = {
        "ios": "13.0",
    },
    ios = {
        "simulator": ["x86_64", "arm64"],
        "device": ["arm64"],
    },
    umbrella_header = "BSText/BSText.h",
    deps = [
        ":BSTextLib",
    ],
    version = ":BSText_Version"
)


Error
When building, I get multiple errors about TextAction not being found:
error: cannot find type 'TextAction' in scope
    @objc open var textTapAction: TextAction?
                                 ^

What I've Tried
Added swiftc_inputs with the header file
Added header to deps
Different combinations of includes paths
Creating module maps
Various combinations of objc_bridging_header, generates_header, and module_name
Consulting Bazel documentation and GitHub issues
Searching through rule_swift and rule_apple repositories for examples
Different build configurations and compiler options
Despite all these attempts and extensive research, I haven't been able to get the Swift code to recognize the Objective-C types. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm running out of ideas to try.
